# How to Deserialize null to Double.NaN (Java, Jackson)

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

**Question:** The Jackson ObjectMapper deserializer is converting a null value to a 0 for a Double field. I need it to either be deserialized to null or Double.NaN. How can I do this?

Do I need to write a custom Double deserializer that maps null to Double.NaN?

**Already tried:** I have scoured the DeserializationFeature Enum but I don't think anything applies. (http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)

**Motivation:** I am deserializing a json object into a custom object (Thing) with code similar to the following. I need the deserializer to keep the value as null or change it to Double.NaN because I need to be able to differential between the 0 case (located at latitude/longitude/altitude = 0) and the null/Double.NaN case (when these values are unavailable).

Jackson deserializing

```
try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Thing t = mapper.readValue(new File("foobar/json.txt"), Thing.class);

    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        ...do stuff..
    }
```

Contents of json.txt. Note that the value null is actually written in the file. It is not left empty. It is not the empty string. It is actuall the word null.

```
{
  "thing" : {
    "longitude" : null,
    "latitude" : null,
    "altitude" : null
  }
}
```

Code for Thing

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Thing implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    Double altitude;

    public Thing(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double altitude) {
         this.latitude = latitude;
         this.longitude = longitude;
         this.altitude = altitude; 

    }
    ...rest of code...
}
```

Comment: There's a DeserializationConfig.Feature for this (see http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html)  and some examples of how to use these at http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig

Comment: Thanks, David. I actually just updated my question wondering if I needed to write a custom Double serializer that maps null to Double.NaN. I am new to this and learning as I go. I will check out your link. :)

Comment: I think that you can only get it to go to null with the DeserializationConfig.Feature, not to NaN.  But have a play and see what works.  I'm afraid I'm not terribly familiar with this stuff, otherwise I'd be able to give you better help.  If you really need NaN, you probably will have to write a custom deserializer.

Comment: I have actually looked at this link before. There are enums which do similar but not close enough and nothing for Double (just double). I will try to write my own then. Appreciate your time :)

Comment: Did you try ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT?  It should do what you want.

Comment: No I did not. The file that I get is uploaded from a mobile app. In the case that those values are unavailable the fields of the json get given null (not "" the empty String). I have no control over this. I just have to deal with it.

Comment: You mean the word "null" is actually written in the field?

Comment: yes, without quotes.

Comment: Ouch, yeah then you'll definitely need your own custom deserialisation code.  I'm sure the makers of Jackson wouldn't have catered for such a use case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will go try to flush that out. Here goes nothing!

Comment: OK, good luck.  I really wish I had been able to help you better.

Comment: Implement your own custom deserializer. Take a look here for an example: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: @filip26 That was perfect. I followed that structure and it works perfectly. Thank you! Problem solved. The only thing is that my actual code is far more complicated so now I have to rewrite a dumbed down version to answer my question for people in the future. hahaha. Thank so much for your help guys (you too, Dave Wallace)!

Comment: @DavidWallace I updated an answer below that is working smoothly. Keep in mind that this is completely adapted code to for the purpose of this question as the actual hierarchical structure of the JSON and POJO classes are too lengthy. Check it out if you are interested since you mentioned you weren't that familiar with the deseralization stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
public class DoubleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String doubleStr = parser.getText();

        if (doubleStr.isEmpty() || doubleStr == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new Double(doubleStr);
    }
}
```

and then in my bean:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleDeserializer.class)
private Double partialPressureCO2;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was to make a custom JSON Deserializer that transformed null into Double.NaN. Adapting what I wrote to match my example code above it would look like this.

```
public class ThingDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Thing> {

@Override
public Thing deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    Thing thingy = new Thing();

    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    if (node.get("latitude").isNull()) {
        thingy.setLatitude(Double.NaN);
    } else {
       thingy.setLatitude(node.get("latitude").asDouble());
    }
    if (node.get("longitude").isNull()) {
        thingy.setLongitude(Double.NaN);
    } else {
        thingy.setLongitude(node.get("longitude").asDouble());
    }
    if (node.get("altitude").isNull()) {
        thingy.setAltitude(Double.NaN);
    } else {
        thingy.setLatitude(node.get("altitude").asDouble());
    }
    return thingy;
}
```

then I registered the deserializer in the class Thing by adding the annotation above the class declaration.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ThingDeserializer.class)
public class Thing implements Serializable { 
            ... class code here ... 
}
```

**Note** I think a better answer would be to deserialize the Double class rather than the Thing class. By deserializing the Double you could generalize the conversion from null to NaN. This would also do away with pulling the specific fields from the node by field name. I could not figure out how to do it on a limited time budget so this is what worked for me. Also, the deserialization is actually being implicitly called by Jackson through a REST api so I am not sure how/if this changes things. I would love to see a solution that would accomplish this though.